# Create Compiled Version of Function

Tags: compile

I am trying to speed up the following function by compilation:

```
cRSI = Compile[{{data, _Real, 1}, {period, _Integer}}, 
  Module[{AvUp, AvDown, lc, pricechange, RS},
   lc = ConstantArray[1., period];
   pricechange = Differences[data];
   AvUp = ListConvolve[lc, UnitStep[pricechange]*pricechange]/period;
   AvDown = 
    ListConvolve[lc, UnitStep[-pricechange]*-pricechange]/period;
   RS = Quiet[100 * AvUp / (AvUp + AvDown)];
   RS[[Flatten@Position[RS, Indeterminate]]] = 50.;
   RS = Join[50.*lc, RS]], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True
  ]
```

Unfortunately I get the following compile errors:

```
Compile::cset: Variable RS of type {_Real,0} encountered in assignment of type {_Real,1}.
Compile::cplist: RS should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function.
```

1. Can anyone help fix the compile errors?
2. Can you suggest any other speed-ups?

Comment: The lines involving `RS` are problematic. You can't use symbolic constructs like `Indeterminate` inside of compiled code. Compiled code only deals with numbers and booleans. Not sure what would be the best way around it.

Comment: You just comment that line with Indeterminate and make sure you don't allow period to be 0. However, ListConvolve is not compilable, so you will not get any speed increase.
You could try the new FunctionCompile, though. Maybe that is eventually useful somewere.